# ES6 Imports inside Export default

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm currently migrating the whole code of a NodeJS application from ES5 to ES6/7.

I'm having trouble when it comes to imports :

First, I understood that making an import directly call the file. For example :

```js
import moduleTest from './moduleTest';
```

This code will go into moduleTest.js and execute it.

So, the real question is about this code :

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import autopopulate from 'mongoose-autopopulate';
import dp from 'mongoose-deep-populate';

import { someUtils } from '../utils';

const types = mongoose.Schema.Types;
const deepPopulate = dp(mongoose);

export default () => {
    // DOES SOMETHING USING types AND deepPopulate
    return someThing;
};

export const anotherModule = () => {
  // ALSO USE types and deepPopulate
};
```

Is this a good practice to have `types` and `deepPopulate` declared outside of the two exports ? Or should I declare them in each export ?

The reason of this question is that I'm having a conflict due to this practice (to simplify, let's say that `dp(mongoose)` will call something that is not declared yet)

Comment: I only see one module. The whole file is the module. `export default ...` and `export const anotherModule ...` are not modules, they are exports. It's completely fine to have module level variables shared by multiple functions in the module. I don't think we can help with your specific problem if you don't tell us what it is.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*declared outside of the two modules*"?

Comment: I meant outside of the two exports, which mean that if I import this file, everything outside these two exports will be executed, which is a problem to me

Comment: And what exactly is that [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: Well, the problem is that the file I'm executing with Node is building a Mongo schema through it's code and using it later. Unfortunately, an import in this file (the code above) is using a schema that's not yet available (since the code from the main file hasn't done it's job ye) so I get an error telling me that the schema is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one 'default' export to a module, or you can have multiple 'named' exports per module. Take a look at the following for a good description of handling exports in ES6: [ECMAScript 6 Modules: The Final Syntax](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I just went through it and it's really helpful!

After a good thinking, I think that I will declare `types` and `deepPopulate` inside each export because I will have conflict if I let them be on top because they will be executed when this file will be imported.

This is pretty disturbing to have these duplicate code, but so be it!